# Flagging an already closed post

Tags: discussion

Is there any **contribution** made to the community by flagging already closed questions?

In the explanation of the [Moderator tools privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), is states :

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be
>   flagged and deleted.

- Do additional flags contribute to the deletion phase of a closed question?
- Is flagging  at that stage "irrelevant" to deletion, as only "close votes" by the 10K users with access to the moderator tools and moderators themselves determine if the question is deleted?

*Don't know when this will be seen or read again in the future, so it might be appropriate to add that at the time of asking this question, I did not have access (yet :) to the moderator tools*

Comment: Flags can draw attention to closed posts needing deletion, but I don't believe they directly contribute to deletion.  A possible exception is spam/offensive flags -- I think a certain number of them will delete a post.

Comment: You need to trust us more :)

Comment: I trust you guys and gals with all my heart :P Just wanna help out where I can...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When flagged, a question/answer will come up in the moderator tools.

This means that it will gain attention and get closed and deleted by those with enough reputation to cast close and delete votes.

Since flagging requires 15 reputation, casting close votes requires 3,000 and casting delete votes requires 10,000 there are many more users that can flag than close and many more that can close than can delete, so the text gives something actionable for all such users (and if you have run out of close votes for the day, you can still flag).

Comment: so flags on closed questions will still be "processed", and the user that acts on the flag can now vote to delete instead of to close.  Its all about bringing attention to that question, whatever phase it is in... got it :)

Answer (score -1):

**Flag if you want a moderator to take some action!** If you flag a closed question for being off-topic, your flag is likely to be declined because there is no need for a moderator to do anything. Think about what you expect a moderator to do about the post, if you think it needs to be deleted or locked, you can flag it. If there is nothing for a moderator to do, pointing out a bad, but already closed post is just wasting the moderator's time.

On an SE 2.0 site without enough 20k users flagging a question for deletion makes some sense. It's probably not necessary on sites where there are enough trusted users that can delete questions without moderator intervention.

Comment: But don't trusted users with access to the moderator tools also process the flag lists?  If so, then flagging will still serve its purpose - raise attention to any user that has deletion priveleges (as long as it gets allocated to a trusted user and not to a moderator :)

Comment: @Lix only the canned flags with predefined reasons, not the general moderator attention flags.

Comment: what do you mean by "canned flags"?